# Execute PHP behind a button WITHOUT using confirm

Tags: php

I have a page that displays a schedule. When the user is satisfied, they click a button to "accept" that schedule. The problem is we used confirm and have now figured out the users aren't hitting ok all the time and we aren't completing the process. 
What can I use instead of:

```
<button>
<a onclick="return confirm('Thank you for confirming your schedule!');" href="?action=report&month=<?php echo $_GET['month']; ?>&year=<?php echo $_GET['year']; ?>&do_Pmail=1">Confirm the Calendar by clicking here</a>
</button>'
```

I just want to execute the code when the user selects the button.
Thanks!

Comment: just remove your `onclick="..."` ?

Comment: remove `onclick="return confirm('Thank you for confirming your schedule!');"`

Comment: Or change text to more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the text to "Press ok to submit your schedule"  Or remove the onclick event. Or change it to return alert("Thank you for confirming your schedule!");